# Regex to match everything after the first N words

Tags: regex, bash, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I want to process annotations in an object detection dataset (YOLO format). The first 5 words are class and xywh coordinates, and everything after is the segmentation data. I want to remove everything after the first 5 words, preferably using bash.

There are about 1.7 million text files. I tried using `cut` and redirecting the output to a new file, but it is too slow on my machine (6k files per minute). Therefore I'd like to be able to do this in-place.

What I want to achieve is similar to:

`for file in *.txt; do sed -i 's/(PATTERN GOES HERE)//g' $file; done`

Input:

```
21 0.0636689 0.582844 0.0979522 0.338453 0.115085 0.248766 0.132235 0.177016 0.156724 0.134422 0.210597 0.132172 0.276706 0.150109 0.367321 0.134422 0.445683 0.10975 0.487304 0.107516 0.575461 0.107516 0.702799 0.145625 0.776263 0.168047 0.84727 0.398984 0.876655 0.410203 0.942782 0.457281 1 0.506609 1 0.596297 1 0.701688 1 0.708406 0.98686 0.964016 0.88401 0.970734 0.759113 0.975219 0.580358 0.977469 0.232628 0.977469 0.00244027 0.988672 0.0122355 0.867594 0.00979522 0.647875
```

Output:

```
21 0.0636689 0.582844 0.0979522 0.338453
```

Comment: Does `cut -f 1-5 "$file"` do what you want?  See [cut](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) and [What is meant by "Now you have two problems"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634).

Comment: please update the question with sample input file and the expected result

Answer (score 2):

using `sed` you could keep the first 5 "words" capturing 5 times 1 or more chars other than spaces.

Then match the rest after it, and replace with capture group 1

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{4\}[^[:space:]]\+\).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl works here:

first create a file with columns:

```bash
$ seq 100 | paste - - - - - - - - - - > file
$ cat file
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100
```

Now keep only the first 5 fields

```bash
$ perl -i -lane 'print "@F[0..4]"' file
```

and we're left with

```bash
$ cat file
1 2 3 4 5
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
51 52 53 54 55
61 62 63 64 65
71 72 73 74 75
81 82 83 84 85
91 92 93 94 95
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` (with `awk` to substitute grep formatting)

**Note**: Keeps field separator formatting intrinsically. Skips lines with less than *n* words.

```
% n=5

% grep -Eno "([[:alnum:],\.]+[[:blank:]]+){$n}" file | 
    awk '/:/{gsub(/.*:/, "", $0); print}'
21   0.0636689 0.582844 0.0979522 0.338453
```

##### Data

```
% tab=$(printf "\t")

% cat << EOF > file
21${tab}0.0636689 0.582844 0.0979522 0.338453 0.115085 0.248766 0.132235 0.177016 0.156724 0.134422 0.210597 0.132172 0.276706 0.150109 0.367321 0.134422 0.445683 0.10975 0.487304 0.107516 0.575461 0.107516 0.702799 0.145625 0.776263 0.168047 0.84727 0.398984 0.876655 0.410203 0.942782 0.457281 1 0.506609 1 0.596297 1 0.701688 1 0.708406 0.98686 0.964016 0.88401 0.970734 0.759113 0.975219 0.580358 0.977469 0.232628 0.977469 0.00244027 0.988672 0.0122355 0.867594 0.00979522 0.647875
EOF
```

PS: Of course this can easily be solved with a single awk, but then its not using regex (Q Title) and field separators can also be tricky.